# cpanel - ssh -How to get cpanel username vis ssh

Tags: cpanel

I don't have whsm , I've installed cpanel on my linux vps .

The problem is , i don't remember my username ,I've my password

Is there anyway to get the username of my cpanel from ssh ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you remember your FTP credentials?

Comment: @ManojKumar no ,I've installed it recently , I haven't got into my cpanel at all

Comment: Did you define your username? If not, try username as `root`

Comment: use `pwd` to get absolute path there you will see like: /home/username and here username is username of cpanel

Answer (score 1):

I can see you have installed cPanel on your server that mean you have root password of your server and through root password you can retrieve your cpanel user name through root password.

Login your server through SSH and try with following command.

```
grep DOMAIN_NAME /etc/trueuserdomains
```

Answer (score 1):

Here sir

```
cat /etc/userdomains
```

It will show to you all **domains** and ***users*** in your cpanel

And if you want to change the password to any user just do

```
passwd user
```

user= the cpanel user you want to change it password